# Custom theme navigation

Tags: permalinks, navigation

I am creating a theme from scratch and have a problem to understand how to link the pages in the navigation.

The pages are written in plain html. And I have "About me", "Contacts", "Blog", etc...

I understand that I can use:

```
<li class="" id="nava"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(1); ?>">Home</a></li>
```

What is the best mechanics to get this type of functionality in wordpress?

If you know a good tutorial about a beginner in wordpress theme development I can make a good use of it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Register your menu**

Register your menu with `register_nav_menus()` after which you can choose that menu from admin area: *Appearance -> Menus*. Add one of these to `functions.php`:

```
<?php
register_nav_menus( array( 'primary' => __( 'Main Menu', 'tt' ) ) );

//'primary' is basically like a slug that can be used to get that specific menu later on
//'Main menu' is the name that appears in admin area: Appearance -> Menus
//'tt' is your translation creds

//If you're not making your strings translatable:
register_nav_menus( array( 'primary' => 'Main Menu' ) );
?>
```

**2. Echo your menu**

Use `wp_nav_menu()` to insert this menu anywhere you want, to header in your case. I've added references below, you can read about different parameters from there but I'll add comments to important ones:

```
<?php
$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => 'primary',   //Same slug as you used to register it
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,  //How many submenus: 0 if only main, -1 if all
    'walker'          => ''
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );


//If you want to keep everything default, you only need to add your menu slug:
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) );

//Just make sure to put wp_nav_menu() where you want your menu to appear

?>
```

**3. Make your menu**

Don't forget to build/add your menu from admin menu: `Appearance -> Menus` and make sure you'll choose the one you registered in *step one*. You can customize, change, edit, add anything you need from there and it will update your menu automatically.

---

**References:**

`register_nav_menus()`: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu

`wp_nav_menu()`: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu